# What is the correct way to instantiate dynamically a template with @ViewChild querying a template reference variable?

Tags: angular

I know I can just pass the template reference variable `mytemplate`  to `*ngTemplateOutlet` and it works.

For learning purposes I want to use different approach via `@ViewChild` decorator.
However I got some errors that I don't understand.

**Minimal Code:**

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:
    `
<ng-template #mytemplate>
<p>Hello World</p>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("mytemplate")
  template!: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**Error Messages:**

```
core.mjs:7640 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.mjs:8207:11)
    at bindingUpdated (core.mjs:14552:17)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:15284:9)
    at AppComponent_Template (app.component.ts:10:16)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12121:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11984:13)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13080:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11774:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12034:13)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.mjs:12101:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is the error which comes only in dev mode
2. But still this should not be there in console.
3. You can manually trigger change detection to avoid this issue

   ```
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngAfterViewChecked(){
        this.cd.detectChanges()
    }
   ```

Link to documnetation : https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: **NOT** use ngAfterViewChecked else **ngAfterViewInit**. NOTE: As the template is always "visible" another way is declared the ViewChild as "static":`@ViewChild("mytemplate",{static:true})`

Comment: @Eliseo: I cannot parse your sentence. :-)

Comment: @Second, Should be: ngAfterViewInit, not AfterViewChecked, see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Another opción is use 
`@ViewChild("mytemplate",{static:true})`, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild). Better?